# Pybossa JS - taskLoaded() function executes twice when fetching 1 task

Tags: javascript, ajax, pybossa

I am currently building a custom task presenter for my PYBOSSA project. I have almost implemented it, but am stuck at the following javascript  function -

```
pybossa.taskLoaded(function(task, deferred) {
    if ( !$.isEmptyObject(task) ) {
        console.log("Hello from taskLoaded");
        // load image from flickr
        var img = $('<img />');
        img.load(function() {
            // continue as soon as the image is loaded
            deferred.resolve(task);
            pybossaNotify("", false, "loading");
        });
        img.attr('src', task.info.url).css('height', 460);
        img.addClass('img-thumbnail');
        task.info.image = img;
        console.log("Task ##"+task.id);
    }
    else {
        deferred.resolve(task);
    }
});
```

According to the docs -

> The pybossa.taskLoaded method will be in charge of adding new items to the JSON task object and resolve the deferred object once the data has been loaded (i.e. when an image has been downloaded), so another task for the current user can be pre-loaded.

But notice my function. I have logged the task ids, the function loads. It loads 2 tasks. After logging, the console shows -

```
Task ##256
Task ##257
```

Also I have tried various other statements. They also execute twice. What I think is that if now I try to insert question of the current task, the function of the next task will also be put along with its respective image. How do I resolve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are seeing double for a good reason :-) PYBOSSA preloads the next task, so the final user does thinks that the next task loads really fast (actually instantly).

While for some projects this might not be a problem, in some cases the user needs to download big images, check other APIs, etc. so it takes 2 or 3 seconds (or even more) to get everything before presenting the task to the user.

PYBOSSA.JS handles this scenario, as soon as the data has been downloaded, it requests a new task, but instead of presenting it, you have it in your window. As you are building your own template, you will have to add that data into the dom (via hidden elements) and then in the pybossa.presentTask method, you will check which task is being loaded, and show/hide the previous one.

In pybossa.saveTask, you can delete the previous DOM elements.

I hope this is now more clear. If you don't want this, you can use jQuery or Axios to request a task, save it and load the next one when you want ;-)

Comment: But each of my tasks can be an image, video or an audio. And each task can have a variable number of questions. Now I am intending to inflate the questions dynamically into HTML using JS. The problem is that both the tasks images are getting inflated. So if task1 has 3 questions and task 2 has 3 questions, Pybossa loads all 6 into the DOM. How do I identify which task to inflate and which to not?

Comment: As I said, you will need to add a div, span, whatever you want into the dom, that identifies itself as the container for the images, videos, questions of the related task. As simple as that. Then you show/hide what you need.

Comment: I got that. But how do I identify which elements belong to the current task and which belong to the next.

Comment: Via the task.ID. Each task has it's own and unique ID, so you will be able to identify them without problems. Just use the ID to load what you need.

Comment: What advantage does this method offer over on demand loading?

Comment: The main advantage is that you will be able to preload in the dom the next task (downloading images for example) while the user is solving the current task. Then, when the user sends the answer, the next task is already in the dom, so all you have to do is show it.

Comment: Hey! Thanks, that helped a lot! If possible, could you please consider upvoting this question if you felt that this question is helpful for the PyBossa community?